# Mobile broadband on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, mate, mobile-broadband

I got a problem with my Dell E6230 Mobile Broadband connection in Ubuntu MATE 20.04. My laptop has a SIM card slot and also I have a SIM in it which has an internet plan active. Tested in Windows 10 and works ok.
Laptops broadband card is a Dell DW5560. Trying to connect in the network manager shows that Mobile Broadband is not enabled. I created a connection using my SIM operator settings but still can't connect to it.
Please see the screenshots attached.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm using my laptop sometimes away from an wifi connection and the mobile connection will be useful.

Thank you!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list` ?

Comment: rfkill list
`2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
4: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: `nmcli connection up id Orange`  is this working? If not edit your question and show `nmcli -p -f general,wifi-properties device show usb0` did you try to deactivate pin in your mobile?

Comment: I have tried your commands but still nothing... SIM card doesn't have a PIN code.